# How can I make a regex that matches any letter in a word X times?

Tags: javascript, regex

Recently, I started to make a word game which involves making words out of the letters of another word. For example, if you have the word "Teutonic", you could make "tonic", "tone", etc. In the game, you can only use the available letters in the word, and not repeat them. That means that while "tonic" would be valid in the above example, "tonico" would not because there is only one "o" in "Teutonic".

My question is basically, how can I make a regular expression so that it searches for **one** instance of the letter and remembers it so that, given the same letter later in the loop, doesn't look for it again?

So if you have "Teutonic" and you are searching using a regex for each letter in "tonico" ("t","o","n","i","c","o"), you would get "true" for every one, except for the last "o".

If you have the word "Pencil", you would get true for "pen", "line", and "pile", but not from "Pipe".

Or if you have "small", you would get true for "mall", "malls" but not "mass".

---

Edit:

Thank you very much for all of your prompt replies! 
I suspected that it wasn't going to be possible with a regex approach, but I wanted to make sure. Instead, I experimented a bit with the array method, thought I didn't get very far.

Thanks again guys!

Comment: I think regex will not solve your problem. An algorithmic answer is enought for you? If so, I will write something.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté: shame on me :-S

Comment: @xdazz: someone needs to realize there is more than just 1 programming language available :-S

Comment: @zerkms Don't worry, happens to me too after too many hours on SO. `=]`

Comment: On topic, you'll probably have to rewrite (or add) some logic to count how many of each character is available when they're available (possibly in an Object), since you probably have some code to store which characters are available, storing their quantity and checking how many are used against how many are available in total when trying to pick a letter shouldn't be much of a problem. (Un)fortunately I'm better with code than words, so without a compilable example it's hard for me to put a proper answer hence I'm leaving it as a comment.

Comment: _"so that, given the same letter later in the loop, doesn't look for it again?"_ What if I formed the word "tint" from "Tuetonic"? You'd need to look for "t" twice...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the string to array, and then compare with array.

```
function checkStr(str1, str2) {
  var arr1 = str1.split(''),
      arr2 = str2.split(''),
      i,j;
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
     if ((j= arr1.indexOf(arr2[i])) === -1) {
        return false;
     } 
     arr1.splice(j, 1);
  }
  return true;
}
// usage
checkStr('small', 'mall');
```

Comment: I think a hash based approach is better for this problem, especially since the game entails comparing many words to a fixed source. Using hashes is faster and (I think) cleaner than splitting and splicing strings all over the place.

Comment: A hash based approach would be better for large arrays, the operation of building a hashtable has some overhead and I think that in the case of single words it just doesn't fit in

Answer (score 2):

Regex is just not a good fit for this task. I would build up a hash of `(character -> occurrences)` for the source and target strings, then compare the counts in the target hash to make sure they are all <= the corresponding counts in the source hash.

If you stick this logic in an object, you can build the source hash only once and then test against it multiple times ([jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/YxMEJ/3/)):

```
function Comparer(sourceStr)
{
    this.buildHash = function(str)
    {
        var hash = new Object();
        for (var i in str)
            hash[str[i]] = (hash[str[i]] || 0) + 1;

        return hash
    };

    this.check = function(testStr)
    {
        var hash = this.buildHash(testStr);

        for (var c in hash)
            if ((this.sourceHash[c] || 0) < hash[c])
                return false;

        return true;
    };     

    this.source = sourceStr;
    this.sourceHash = this.buildHash(sourceStr);
};

var comp = new Comparer("teutonic");
alert(comp.check("tonic"));  // true
alert(comp.check("tint"));   // true
alert(comp.check("tonico")); // false
alert(comp.check("asdf"));   // false
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never worked with hashes before, so I will look into this and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure this is a suitable use-case for a regular expression?  I think because you're looking to use the letters in the original word, in different orders to what they appear, the expression is no longer "regular".

I would imagine that if it can be done, it would require the use of very complex back-references.

I'd personally attack this using some kind of custom (or pre-existing domain-specific) algorithm.

But I must admit I'm not a regex expert so happy to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 0):

```
// It may not matter, but you can also compare strings without creating arrays.

String.prototype.contains= function(word){
    var seed= String(this), i= 0, len= word.length, next= '';
    while(i<len){
        next= word.charAt(i++);
        if(seed.indexOf(next)== -1) return false;
        seed= seed.replace(next, '');
    }
    return word;
}


//testing 
var startword= 'teutonic',report='startword= '+startword, 
list= ['ton', 'on', 'out', 'tout', 'tone', 'tonic', 'tune', 'nice', 
'note', 'not','tot', 'tote', 'ice', 'tic', 'nick', 'cone', 'con', 'cut', 'cute'];

var failed=list.filter(function(itm){
    return !startword.contains(itm);
});

report+= failed.length? '\n'+failed.length+' incorrect: '+failed+';\n':'';
report+=list.length+' correct: '+list+';\n';
alert(report);


/*  returned value: (String)
startword= teutonic
1 incorrect: nick;
19 correct: ton,on,out,tout,tone,tonic,tune,nice,note,
not,tot,tote,ice,tic,nick,cone,con,cut,cute;

*/
```